# how do i return an NSString or NSUrl from my didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo?

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, uiimagepickercontroller

Good day, I am trying to implement the UIImagePickerController inside my selectFile function. (followed this tutorial in [appcoda](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-camera-iphone-app/)) but code below is a bit tweaked now based on what i want

```
@implementation FileBrowser
-(void)selectFile{
    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.allowsEditing = NO;
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
}

#pragma mark - Image Picker Controller delegate methods

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    NSURL *refURL = [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL];
    NSString *myURL = [refURL absoluteString]; //not in tutorial, I'm trying to grab the url/path of the image here, with an intention of returning it to "callFileBrowser"

    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}

@end
```

Based on what i understood, my imagePickerController function is called when user selects an image. My question is how do i return(or get) the url instead? I have a C function on the same file (but outside @implemetation), this function calls my selectFile and is supposed to return the url/path of what the user has chosen.

```
char* callFileBrowser(){
[fileBrowser selectFile];
//return myURL here;
}
```

I hope i was able to explain everything properly. Any advice would greatly be appreciated. thanks.

Comment: Miu, have you thought about using ALAssets library to load your photos? It has asset media URL to the file, ALAssets is a lower level library but it allows you to have a custom looking photo picker. I believe photo picker requires portrait orientation the last time I used it on the iPad, which is a problem when if your app only works in landscape mode.

Comment: i haven't thought of that, i'll research about that now. i really just wanted to get the path. thanks for the advice Zhang

Comment: You could alternatively create a property to store the URL in your viewController.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it is possible with the current design. callFileBrowser() is called to pick a image, then immediately it is required to return a value. We don't know when user will be done picking, I suggest you to post a notification in didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo when the url is ready to notify other object who needs it.

Comment: so what i'll do is create the notification in didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo .. and maybe pass my (NSDictionary *)info to another function, let's say grabReadyURL, and that function will handle what needs to be done?

Comment: Yes,that's right,the other function will receive your dictionary with url in it, then you can handle from there. It depends on where the function is, if it is in FileBrowser,you can call it directly, if it is in another file, you can also use Delegation.

Comment: I'll accept this answer coz it helped me think of an alternative way of implementing what i want. Thanks a lot gabbler!